# Wordpress API for blogging website

Tags: node.js, wordpress

I am having a existing wordpress app www.fiz-x.com, its a all category blogging app which we post from our dashboard. What I need is that I'll make a mobile app for my web app. But how can I get the data from my web app? Means how will I get the APIs of my web app which I can easily call from my mobile frontend and will get the response. Hope someone will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 4.4 release of WordPress which will probably be out in December of this year you'll have access to the brand new [REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/).

If you can't wait that long you can use the [REST plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) which the official API is built off of.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for the nice information. So I just have to install the plugin from my dashboard and I can have the APIs or do I have to create APIs there? I mean I am not getting the exact answer regarding APIs url and its response

Comment: Installing and activating that plugin will expose HTTP endpoints that you can query using whatever programming or command line environment you want and will return JSON data for you to consume as needed. For instance, once you activate it (assuming you have pretty permalinks enabled, too, per their documentation) you should see your posts by going to `/wp-json/posts`. See [their documentation](http://wp-api.org/) for more specifics on their API.